# Python: Passing arguments when running an external command

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am calling an external program like this

```
call(["./myProgram", myArgs])
```

How can I pass a list of arguments? myProgram takes 3 parameters like this

```
myProgram param1 param2 param3
```

specifiying arguments seperately like below works

```
call(["./myProgram", param1 ,param2, param3])
```

, but how can I use a list/array of arguments, like

```
myArgs=[param1,param2,param3]
```

I am getting this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
raise child_exception TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just concatenate the lists:

```
call(['./myProgram'] + myArgs)
```

The first argument must be a list of strings; simply *build* that list from two separate lists.